# Is it a good practice or not to use inheritance when creating Models in Web API with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, asp.net-web-api2

I have 4 model classes that share 10 same properties, I know I can create another class as base class and set the 4 models to inherit the base class so I don't need to set extra properties in these models. However, I am concerned that in the EF generated Controller for all these class inheritance, there will be a join performed in the underlining SQL strings. If I don't use inheritance, I know it will just be a simple Select call.

What is the best practice to handle this situation?

Comment: Is it a code-first approach?

Comment: yes, it is code first.